# how do i add an image in the background in css from a folder?

Tags: html, background

I have an image, and from what I've seen in W3schools you can just use
`body background = farm.jpg`
And that works, but it says and I've seen people say this, that it can work with css with

`background-image: url(farm.jpg)` (with and without quotes)

yet whenever i try it can't find the picture.Do I need to put it in a separate folder?

Comment: It works. You can have the image in the same folder (directory) or in other as long as the path to it is correct relative to the page. Post your full code to see what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It depenteds to where is your css file , put your css file and image file into same place, and try below

```
background-image: url("frame.jpg");
```

Or you can use / to start from root folder.

```
background-image: url("/frame.jpg");
```

[Read this.](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Answer (score 0):

(1) https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Unfourtunately the  background attribute is not supported in HTML5. You must use CSS instead.

(2) You can use the code example form this page, what works:

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Hintergrundfarben_und_-bilder/background-image

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 page">
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("background.png");
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Test.</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.