# How to use background-image: with php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How can I use background-image: url() in conjunction with php in order to obtain the directory of the image I would like to display.

**CSS**

```
.imageGallery {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
background-image: url('<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/images/visitus.png');
}
```

Currently, this css does not work. No background image is displayed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageGallery">
</div>
```

For example:

this works fine

```
<img src='<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/images/home.png' class="headImage" />
```

but this doesn't

```
    background-image: url('<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/images/visitus.png');
```

Comment: Web server error log showing a 404 for visitus.png? If you view source, do you see it render the directory you expect? If you visit that directory directly can you load the file? If home.png works, I'd try that for your background-image temporarily.

Comment: Where is your css file ? In root ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this two options bellow

**CSS**

```
.imageGallery {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
background-image: url('images/visitus.png');
}
```

**HTML** with inline CSS

```
<div class="imageGallery" style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/images/visitus.png')">
</div>
```

If you use the second option, you need to remove background image url from your css rule for that element. Hope it helps

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I'm trying the first solution you mentioned, but the image still doesn't show up. http://imgur.com/a/mBzQL

Comment: I see your image path ` ../images/visitus.png` is different for the first solution remove the ` ../` from your path. I always use this for wordpress theme case

Answer (score 0):

It depenteds to where is your css file , put your css file and image file into same place, and try below

```
background-image: url("frame.jpg");
```

Or you can use / to start from root folder.

```
background-image: url("/frame.jpg");
```

[Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293445/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-background-in-css-from-a-folder/44293753#44293753)